# GraphQL Mongoose promise best practices

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

Using GraphiQL, I'm able to update a user with the following command (1). 
I'm able to return the actual user with the service (3).

**Is there simpler/more compact way of returning the user after an update? (seen how easy it is when creating a user).**

(1) GraphiQL mutation command
    mutation {
      updateUser(id: "1", firstName: "Bob"){
        firstName
      }
    }

(2) the mutation:

```
const mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
updateUser: {
  type: UserType,
  args: {
    id:         { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
    firstName:  { type: GraphQLString },
    age:        { type: GraphQLInt },
    companyId:  { type: GraphQLString }
  },
  resolve(parentValue, args){
    return UserService.updateUser(args);
  }
},
})
```

(3) the service:

```
function updateUser(args) {
  var {id} = args;
  return User.findOne({id})
    .then(user => {
      if(!user){throw new Error('No user found')}
      return User.update({id}, args)
         .then(() => {
           return User.findOne({id})
         })
    })
},
function addUser(args) {
  const user = new User(args);
  return user.save(args);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using `mongoose`:

```
function updateUser(args) {
  var {id} = args;

  return await User.findOneAndUpdate({ id }, args, { new: true });
},
```

Comment: Thanks Aaroh, that's great. I can't figure out how comes I did not find that one by myself... I searched however..

Comment: Ah I forgot to mention you probably want to await the operation. Check my answer again.